# How to solve an exception java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting the following error while connecting to MYSQL

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/chatdb`

Here is my code:

```
public class Connect(){ 
    Connection conn;
    public Connection getConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                       ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/chatdb","myserver","pass");
            System.out.println("Database connection established");
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

I dont know what is the problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below for getting the connection:

```
getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName","username", "password");//presuming that mysql server is running on port 3306
```

Since `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` didnt throw exception, i believe driver jar is in place(classPath). Just correct the URL for getting the connection, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your MySQL-Driver(.jar) **is not** on the classpath.</strike>

Further, **your connection String is wrong**, when you want to connect to MySQL

It should look like:
`jdbc:mysql://[host][:port]/[database][?property1][=value1]`

as example:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=monty&password=greatsqldb`

But in **your** connection string, you "requested" a driver for SQL-Server (`jdbc:sqlserver`).

**EDIT**:
you can take a look at this step-by-step tuturial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: make an environment variable "classpath" and its value should be the file path of your sql database's .jar file

Comment: As there is no ClassNotFoundException, it should not be an issue with classpath, its able to load the class